Can I use the plain form with か in the end of a sentence to make a question?
Like, instead of

これは本ですか

can I say

これは本だか?

Instead of

この本をもうお読みになりましたか

can I say

この本をもうお読みになったか?

What about adjectives?

I don't think anyone uses か with だ


これは本だか?

This is incorrect. The copula だ is never used with か. You should say "これは本か?" (which is bookish and can sound very blunt in speech) or "これは本？" (which is suitable for ordinary casual speech).

Regarding plain-form of a verb + か, yes, this combination is correct, but is considered a bookish or literary style of forming a question. It's fine in formal book titles and such (real examples include this and this), but should almost always be avoided in spoken Japanese.

この本をもうお読みになったか?

This sentence might be grammatically correct, but it sounds highly unnatural because it mixes honorific speech with a literary style. While a few fictional characters (e.g., sages, nobles, or politicians in historical settings) might speak this way, you must avoid this in real life.
Even if we remove the honorific verb:

この本をもう読んだか?

This sounds much more blunt than you might think, almost like Terminator. See also my answer here, too. In ordinary informal speech, you have to say "この本(を)もう読んだ?" without か.
